# Conflict between global variables c/c++

Tags: c++, global-variables, conflicting-libraries

I'm using two files ".h" in which there are 3 global variables with the same names.

We suppose to have these files:

- A.h => inside it there are "union var1", "union var2" and "#define LENGTH 20".
- B.h => inside it there are "union var1", "union var2" and "#define LENGTH 60".
- C.h => that imports both A.h and B.h.

When I compile C.h, I have an error cause of the conflict for same variables name.

I don't want to modify their names because They are inside public libraries (I would like to use them as they are!).
This is my problem.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: can you pls post some code snippets?

Comment: By tagging this both `c` and `c++`, you make it very hard to give good answers. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, C++ actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, header files (".h") never get "compiled", strictly speaking, so there is no such thing as `When I compile C.h`. Only `.cpp` files, which of course **include** these header files get compiled.

Second, if your program needs to include the two header files that reference different variables that have the same name, then you probably have some bad design problem.

Third, I think (?, don't use unions very much...) that you need to define a name for a union.

Otherwise, a solution could be to define different namespaces to distinguish the two:

```
// A.h
namespace aa {
    union myType { int m1; float m2; }
    myType var1;
}
```

.

```
// B.h
namespace bb {
    union myType { int m1; float m2; }
    myType var1;
}
```

.

```
// C.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

...
    aa::var1.m1 = 1;
    bb::var1.m1 = 2;
```

Comment: @juanchopanza feel free to correct, you got the idea ... ;-)

Comment: Well, no, if you're posting an answer, _you_ get the syntax correct!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, ok ok, I though this was a collaborative site, sorry ;-) I think my answer is correct, now. But from the votes, I understand it is better to post an answer giving a general direction with no code sample than to post a detailed answer ;-)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Yeah, but IMHO that's not really SO's purpose: in the present case, obviously the OP didn't get much help from David's answer, although it was technically correct. But that's the way it goes...

Comment: Re the bad design problem: you don't always have a choice.  Back when I started C++, the USL library was widely used for its class `String` (among other things), and of course, GUI software would usually have to include `X.h`.  Which had a `#define String ...`.

Comment: yes it works. In this way I have modified the two libraries (I don't like, but I don't have any other idea)... :S

Answer (score 6):

Quarantine each public library so that you don't need to include both header files in any single file. Files may use one library or they may use the other, but not both. You will need to create wrappers for functionality that you need, wrapping whichever library is easiest to wrap and using your wrapper, instead of the library directly, in code that uses the other library.

Comment: Ok, but Can you show me some examples of this "wrapper"? I'm not able to understand!

Comment: A "wrapper" is a function that calls one or more other functions, in this case, the functions from the library. Your wrapper function, and its parameters, would be defined in its own header file. So instead of calling the wrapped function, which require you to include a header file that causes you problems, you all the wrapper function, which doesn't. Basically, a wrapper provides the same functionality a totally different interface -- in this case one that you can design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

LIB_FILE.H

```
extern union_type var1; // declaration
extern union_type var2; // declaration
```

LIB_FILE.cpp

```
union_type var1;  // definition
union_type var2;  // definition
```

FILE A.H

```
#include "LIB_FILE.H"
```

FILE B.H

```
#include "LIB_FILE.H"
```

FILE C.H

```
#include "A.H"
#include "B.H"
```

You need to distinguish declaration from definition of the global variables.